# How to add data type as date in angular formly?

Tags: angularjs, angular-formly

Is it possible to add input type as date in angular formly.? I was trying it using **type:date** but it is not defined in it. So, how to get it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I recommend you take a look at the resources at http://learn.angular-formly.com/

Specifically, what you're looking for is creating Custom Templates ([video](http://docs.angular-formly.com/docs/learn-angular-formly#section--custom-templates-https-egghead-io-lessons-angularjs-angular-formly-custom-templates-pl-7-), [example](http://angular-formly.com/#/example/custom-types/custom-templates)). There's even an example that uses [UI Datepicker](http://angular-formly.com/#/example/integrations/ui-datepicker).